# how to config max_execution_time at Azure wordpress on linux web app

Tags: php, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

I'm running wordpress on Azure linux web app services and need to config php.ini " max_execution_time" but in the app setting there isn't any option for it here is the screenshot from web app setting page.
please advise on how can i config php.ini
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, you needn’t to modify the `php.ini` file.You can follow below steps to modify " max_execution_time":

1. For Linux App Service ,follow the 2 steps in [This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/10/09/logging-php-errors-in-wordpress-2/) to add or modify `.htaccess` file.
2. Add or modify `.htaccess` file.  In this file , add the PHP configuration you want  to modify using the format below .

Example:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
```

Please let me know if it helps!