# Azure app services: Set max_execution_time

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a php script to import the data into the database. And I would like to import if possible 10000 lines. Except that I'm blocked by the timout because max_execution_time=300 in php.ini
So I did some research and among the solutions I tried the following:
1- `<IfModule mod_php7.c> php_value max_execution_time 0 </IfModule>` in .htaccess (pulic folder)

2- `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` in my controller (I use Laravel)

3- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-windows#customize-phpini-settings

4- I combined all these solutions

None of these ideas work.
Is there anything to check or uncheck in the admin area?
Please, does anyone have an idea of what to do?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the `php.ini` file.

You can  modify `.htaccess` file, add php configuration like below.

Example:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
```

**Thanks for Wayne Yang's help, for more details, you can refer his answer.**

[how to config max_execution_time at Azure wordpress on linux web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109923/how-to-config-max-execution-time-at-azure-wordpress-on-linux-web-app)